# Robust colored background for parts of the document

Tags: color, adjustbox

I would like to set off certain parts of my document by giving them a colored background. With the help of `adjustbox` I was able to write an environment that does more or less what I want: It puts its contents in a borderless, unpadded box with a colored background.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newenvironment{shaded}
  {\par\noindent\adjustbox{frame=0pt,bgcolor=yellow,minipage=\textwidth}\bgroup}
  {\egroup\par}
```

The problem is that this is, well, a box. It cannot be broken across pages, and it doesn't play nice with floats etc., which cannot be encountered while creating a box. (Thanks to the `minipage` option, footnotes are captured at the bottom of the shaded area instead of disappearing entirely). For my particular use, restructuring the document to avoid these problems is not an option.

So the question is: Are there any solutions for creating a colored background that are as transparent as possible? I've seen a number of answers for coloring [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63883/color-entire-table), [code snippets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28179/colored-background-in-inline-listings), [boxing that supports page breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52943/12092), [complete pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25137/12092)([a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25137/12092),  [b](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82206/background-color-gradient-for-entire-document)), etc., but nothing I can see how to adapt for more general use.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,adjustbox}

\newenvironment{shaded}
  {\par\noindent\adjustbox{frame=0pt,bgcolor=yellow,minipage=\textwidth}\bgroup}
  {\egroup\par}

\begin{document}

\section{Regular section}
This section is not highlighted. 
This text is just padding to indicate the natural line length. 

\begin{shaded}
This is set with a colored background.

\section{Highlighted section}
This entire section is, 
actually.\footnote{This footnote is trapped in the minipage.}

\begin{table}
This float triggers an error and disappears.
\end{table}

\end{shaded}

\section{The rest of the document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package for this.

Comment: The `framed` package is a different option.

Comment: Related: [Including multiple figures/subfigures within an fbox (minipage)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40011/including-multiple-figures-subfigures-within-an-fbox-minipage/46698#46698) or  [Grey box code and lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23604/grey-box-code-and-lists/23617#23617)

Comment: Thank you both, `framed` seems like the way to deal with the page breaks. Unfortunately it's still a box and has the rest of the shortcomings...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following packages can be used for shade environments and they allow page breaks:

- [boites](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/boites)
- [framed](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/framed)
- [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed)

Here a suggestion using `framed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{framed,xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{red!20}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{shaded}
\blindtext\blindtext
\blindtext\blindtext
\end{shaded}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

A more modern package which allows you a comfortable configuration of the frame is the package `mdframed`. Below is a simple example with a shaded background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=red!20]{shaded}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{shaded}
\blindtext\blindtext
\blindtext\blindtext
\end{shaded}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Related questions are:

- [Including multiple figures/subfigures within an fbox (minipage)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40011/including-multiple-figures-subfigures-within-an-fbox-minipage/46698#46698)
- [Grey box code and lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23604/grey-box-code-and-lists/23617#23617)

Comment: Really??? No `mdframed` example? :-)  Made me think that there were perhaps two users with this userid!!

Comment: @PeterGrill: Can I use my own package? I think it's a little bit egocentric.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The `boites` package is a good illustration of how good TeX is at avoiding (unintentionally) rivers. The examples all use blah, blah...thanks for reminding me about the package.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: The package `boites` uses an interesting splitting algorithm which makes it interesting ;-) Of course the user won't see it ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Nah I don't think so. It's not as if you are trying to sell it.  If it bothers you, you can always add a disclaimer that you are the author.  But, if I was new and didn't know about` mdframed`, and came across this question I would conclude that `framed` wass being recommended over `mdframed`.  Plus `mdframed` is such an awesome package. I haven't used `framed` so I am not implying that there is anything wrong with that package.

Comment: @marco, I tried your code for `mdframed` and the line breaks are great, but the box contents are indented from the boundary. I'm aiming for a "tight box" (as with my `adjustbox` example). Is there a quick way to remove all padding, or do I have to zero each spacing option separately?

Comment: @alexis: There is no indention. Can you add an example to your previous answer or ask a new one to show the issue. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I guess it's what you call the `innermargins` (`innerleftmargin`, `innertopmargin`, etc.), which are non-zero by default according to the documentation. Do I need to zero each one separately? (My example uses `adjustbox`, so the colored text is exactly as wide as the surrounding text.)

Comment: @alexis: Yes. The two length are non zero length. `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` are 0pt.