# Picture with grey box as background

Tags: graphics, backgrounds

Does anyone know how I can set up a grey box as background for my images like in this example in the picture below?

[image: Picture with grey box as bg]

I had found a good example in [Grey box code and lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23604/grey-box-code-and-lists) but it doesn't work with a picture inside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand\greybox[1]{%
  \vskip\baselineskip%
  \par\noindent\colorbox{lightgray}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
  }%
  \vskip\baselineskip%
}

\begin{document}
    \greybox{Content of Grey Box}
...

// but it doesn't work with picture inside:

...
    \greybox{
       \begin{figure}[ht]
          \footnotesize
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{illustrationen/mygraphic.png}
          \begin{flushright}
             Some Reference
          \end{flushright}
          \caption{Title}
          \label{fig:label}
       \end{figure}
    }

\end{document}
```

Anyone a simple idea for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot enclose the `figure` environment within the argument to `\greybox`.  Rather, enclose the **contents** of the `figure` environment within the argument to `\greybox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand\greybox[1]{%
  \vskip\baselineskip%
  \par\noindent\colorbox{lightgray}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
  }%
  \vskip\baselineskip%
}

\begin{document}
    \greybox{Content of Grey Box}
...

// but it doesn't work with picture inside:

...
       \begin{figure}[ht]
    \greybox{
          \footnotesize
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image}
          \begin{flushright}
             Some Reference
          \end{flushright}
          \caption{Title}
          \label{fig:label}
    }
       \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily using the `adjustbox` package. It gives you a `bgcolor` key for the background color. For multi-line content you need to use the `minipage` key first. You can also easily select the margin around the image by using the `margin` key. 
If all is `\textwidth` wide then you don't need to center the content, otherwise add the `center` key at the very end.

Forthermore, e.g. a frame could be easily added by using e.g. the `frame` key, in which case you should substract `2\fboxrule` from the either the `minipage` width or the `margin`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{mwe}% just for example text and images

\begin{document}
\lipsum[0-1]

      \begin{figure}[ht]
          \footnotesize
          \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth-6pt,margin=3pt,bgcolor=black!40}
          \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image}
          \adjustbox{right}{Some Reference}% add `minipage=<width>` before `right` if reference has multiple lines
          \caption{Title}
          \label{fig:label}
      \end{adjustbox}
       \end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]